# Adding times from a song list

Tags: javascript, html

I am playing around with HTML and want to see if certain things are doable. I have a table of five songs which has the following data elements: song name, artist, duration and album. I have turned them into a table and now I would like to make a statistics table that shows how many songs, how many artists, and what the total time is to play the whole song list. I would like a little help on figuring out how to add all the times together from the table without just hard coding the actual number. Is this possible?

Here is my code so far (I don't know how much to add but I don't want to put the whole thing):

```
<script>
    var playlist = [
    {
        "Song Name": "X",
        "Artist": "Schoolboy Q",
        "Duration": "4:27",
        "Album": "Black Panther the Album"
    },
    {
        "Song Name": "White Sand",
        "Artist": "Migos",
        "Duration": "3:22",
        "Album": "Culture 2"
    },
    {
        "Song Name": "Goat 2.0",
        "Artist": "Eric Bellinger",
        "Duration": "3:07",
        "Album": "Goat 2.0"
    },
    {
        "Song Name": "No Drama",
        "Artist": "Tinashe",
        "Duration": "3:20",
        "Album": "No Drama"
    },
    {
        "Song Name": "Telephone Calls",
        "Artist": "A$AP Mob",
        "Duration": "3:50",
        "Album": "Cozy Tapes Vol. 1 Friends -"
    }

<body>
    <h1>Music Playlist</h1>
    <h2>Music Table</h2>
    <table id="music"></table><br><br>
    <h2>Updated Music Table</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Song</th><th>Artist</th><th>Duration</th><th>Album</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="playmusic">

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        /*document.write(music[0].First);*/
        var text = "";
        var newtext = "";
        /*var x;*/
        for (var x in playlist) {
            if (playlist.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                var obj = playlist[x];
                for (var y in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(y)) {
                        text += "<tr><td align='right'>" + y + "</td><td>" + obj[y] + "</td></tr>";
                        /*document.write(y + " -> " + obj[y] + '\n');*/
                    }
                }
                newtext += "<tr><td>" + obj['Song Name'] + "</td><td>" + obj['Artist'] + "</td><td>" + obj['Duration'] + "</td><td>" + obj['Album'] + "</td><tr>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("music").innerHTML = text;
        document.getElementById("playmusic").innerHTML = newtext;
        document.getElementByID("music").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
    <p>
        To go back to the Index page: <a href="http://wlr3iii.github.io/index.html">Click</a>
    </p>
```

Would I try and loop through "duration" and find a function that lets me add the numbers found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` to pull out the durations into a separate array, `reduce` to sum all the numbers, and a couple of additional lines of code to correct the minutes/seconds:

```js
var playlist=[{"Song Name":"X","Artist":"Schoolboy Q","Duration":"4:27","Album":"Black Panther the Album"},{"Song Name":"White Sand","Artist":"Migos","Duration":"3:22","Album":"Culture 2"},{"Song Name":"Goat 2.0","Artist":"Eric Bellinger","Duration":"3:07","Album":"Goat 2.0"},{"Song Name":"No Drama","Artist":"Tinashe","Duration":"3:20","Album":"No Drama"},{"Song Name":"Telephone Calls","Artist":"A$AP Mob","Duration":"3:50","Album":"Cozy Tapes Vol. 1 Friends -"}]

function addDurations(data) {
  const total = playlist
    .map(el => el.Duration.split(':'))
    .reduce((p, c) => {
      p.minutes += Number(c[0]);
      p.seconds += Number(c[1]);
      return p;
    }, { minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });

  const whole = Math.floor(total.seconds / 60);
  total.minutes += whole;
  total.seconds = total.seconds % 60;
  return total;
}

console.log(addDurations(playlist))
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. I'm still learning this and really appreciate your help